I want to see the implementation of the render method in React, but when using VSCode's 'Go to Source Definition'
I want to see the implementation of the render method in React, but when using VSCode's 'Go to Source Definition', it shows 'No source definitions found.' How can I navigate to the specific implementation of the render method?

I tried 'Go to Definition', 'Go to Type Definition', and 'Go to Implementations', but they all redirected to the places where I called the render method in my code.


typescript Version5.5.2、vscode Version1.90.2   node.js v14.18.0
